# Problems scraping headlines from website in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to extract all the headlines from this website: https://www.theguardian.com/international. I have tried so many xpaths, but none gives me the headlines, although the code works. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

This is my code:

```
guardian_url <- "https://www.theguardian.com/international"
guardian <- read_html(guardian_url)

headlines <- guardian %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = '//html/body/div[3]/div') %>% 
  html_text2()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding

"https://www.theguardian.com/international" %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_elements(".fc-item__title") %>% 
  html_text2()

#>   [1] "UK Dover asylum centre not operating legally, concedes minister"                                                        
#>   [2] "Exclusive Bahraini death row prisoner pleads with pope to aid his release"                                              
#>   [3] "Live Russia-Ukraine war: Blinken hails Turkish help as grain export deal resumes"                                       
#>   [4] "‘We’re facing a defining moment’ Biden urges Americans to take a stand against political violence"                      
#>   [5] "Live UK: biggest interest rate rise in decades expected as Bank of England battles inflation"                           
#>   [6] "North Korea ICBM launch may have been a failure, South’s military says"                                                 
#>   [7] "Twitter Company may ‘halve its workforce’ as key investor backs job cuts"                                               
#>   [8] "China Father of three-year-old blames zero-Covid policy for son’s death"                                                
#>   [9] "Hong Kong Exiles in UK unnerved by ‘weak’ response to beating of protester"                                             
#>  [10] "Myanmar Experts warn of aid ‘catastrophe’, after junta law change"                                                      
#>  [11] "Analysis Grain deal U-turn offers lesson in calling Putin’s bluff"                                                      
#>  [12] "At a glance What we know on day 253 of the invasion"                                                                    
#>  [13] "UK Kremlin to summon British ambassador over drone attacks on Black Sea fleet"                                          
#>  [14] "Roman Abramovich UK adds two ‘business associates’ of former Chelsea owner to Russia sanctions list"                    
#>  [15] "‘He is poised to open the floodgates’ Can Twitter survive Elon Musk – or even thrive?"                                  
#>  [16] "The long read The many meanings of moss"                                                                                
#>  [17] "No fun rides but plenty of spirit Studio Ghibli offers anime fans a new walk in the park"                               
#>  [18] "Germany's balancing act Scholz heads to China amid questions over strategy"                                             
#>  [19] "Weird: The Al Yankovic Story review Daniel Radcliffe biopic packed with wacky walk-ons"                                 
#>  [20] "‘No darkness is for ever’ Can an activist in exile persuade the Taliban to allow teaching on TV?"                       
#>  [21] "Nil By Mouth review Gary Oldman’s overwhelming study of family violence"                                                
#>  [22] "‘More dignity’ Aid organisations switch to cash in drought-hit Ethiopia"                                                
#>  [23] "Europe Climate warming at twice rate of global average, says report"                                                    
#>  [24] "No more drinking water, little food: our island is a field of bones"                                                    
#>  [25] "Rishi Sunak PM U-turns on decision not to attend Cop27"                                                                 
#>  [26] "Cop27 Egyptian hunger striker may die in prison, Nobel laureates warn world leaders attending summit"                   
#>  [27] "Fossil fuel burning once caused a mass extinction – now we’re risking another"                                          
#>  [28] "World leaders at Cop27 in Egypt must demand the release of Alaa Abd El-Fattah"                                          
#>  [29] "The ProPublica-Vanity Fair report on Covid-19’s origins is explosive. Is it reliable?"                                  
#>  [30] "Benjamin Netanyahu may be back – but the true victory belongs to Israel’s far right"                                    
#>  [31] "Can you ‘lose’ an accent? And more importantly, why would you want to?"                                                 
#>  [32] "With the global economy on the rocks, quiet quitting is no longer a thing"                                              
#>  [33] "Qatar calling its critics racist opens a debate that may be worth having"                                               
#>  [34] "Pancakes, shakes and KFC When Barkley tried to eat his way out of the 76ers"                                            
#>  [35] "‘Any problem you have, it’s nothing’ Rico’s brotherly inspiration"                                                      
#>  [36] "World Series Astros silence Phillies in Game 4 with rare no-hitter"                                                     
#>  [37] "Cricket Yorkshire racism hearing to be held in public after request from Rafiq"                                         
#>  [38] "T20 World Cup Australia wary of ‘pushing too hard’ to improve run rate"                                                 
#>  [39] "Chelsea 2-1 Dinamo Zagreb Chilwell set to miss World Cup with hamstring injury"                                         
#>  [40] "To criticise or not to criticise Are women’s football pundits too nice?"                                                
#>  [41] "Europe French-German friendship ‘still alive’ as Macron meets Scholz amid tensions"                                     
#>  [42] "‘Nobody forced us’ The Greek builder who saved 80 Afghans from the sea"                                                 
#>  [43] "Italy Fall of Liz Truss gives far right a lesson in what not to do"                                                     
#>  [44] "‘Get Igor Girkin’ Hopes MH17 suspect could be captured fighting in Ukraine"                                             
#>  [45] "Israel election Netanyahu thanks voters as rightwing bloc extends Israeli election lead"                                
#>  [46] "Africa Invasive mosquito could disrupt ‘landscape of malaria’ after cases rise"                                         
#>  [47] "Twitter exodus Company faces murky future as top managers flee the nest"                                                
#>  [48] "Climate crisis Big agriculture warns farming must change or risk ‘destroying the planet’"                               
#>  [49] "Hillsong Church Founder Brian Houston breaks silence with video stating ‘I will fight’ criminal charge in Australia"    
#>  [50] "Denmark election Result keeps Social Democrats at the helm"                                                             
#>  [51] "Seoul crowd crush Local police offices raided in investigation"                                                         
#>  [52] "Exclusive UN poverty envoy tells Britain this is ‘worst time’ for more austerity"                                       
#>  [53] "Ethiopian civil war Parties agree truce to end hostilities"                                                             
#>  [54] "Just Stop Oil Protesters who targeted Girl with a Pearl Earring jailed by Dutch court"                                  
#>  [55] "Good Night Oppy review Cutesy Spielberg-assisted Mars documentary"                                                      
#>  [56] "Dinosaurs by Lydia Millet review Can a wealthy man be good?"                                                            
#>  [57] "‘Did I notice a dark side?’ The true story behind serial killer drama The Good Nurse"                                   
#>  [58] "Selena Gomez My Mind & Me review: a fascinating and frustrating pop doc"                                                
#>  [59] "Avatar: The Way of Water James Cameron releases extended trailer"                                                       
#>  [60] "Killer Sally review A warped true-crime tale of bodybuilder murder"                                                     
#>  [61] "How to cook the perfect ... Pumpkin gnocchi"                                                                            
#>  [62] "Rail route of the month The slow train to Skagen, Denmark, where the North Sea meets the Baltic"                        
#>  [63] "A moment that changed me I threw away the sheet music and all the colour and passion I had for the harp came back to me"
#>  [64] "Pushing Buttons Pushing Buttons: Freaky games form some of my most vivid childhood memories"                            
#>  [65] "Kitchen aide Why parmesan rinds are a cook’s secret ingredient"                                                         
#>  [66] "From pirates’ hideout to Dalí’s bolthole Cadaqués, star of Spain’s Costa Brava"                                         
#>  [67] "US midterm elections 2022 Republicans and Democrats spend big on ads"                                                   
#>  [68] "US midterm elections 2022 Why is Nike founder Phil Knight so desperate to prevent a Democratic win in Oregon?"          
#>  [69] "Cambodia’s modern slavery nightmare The human trafficking crisis overlooked by authorities"                             
#>  [70] "Psychology I was an unhappy teenager, among lonely people, in thrall to a charismatic leader – had I joined a cult?"    
#>  [71] "‘This is apartheid’ Cape Town slum residents condemn forced removals"                                                   
#>  [72] "‘I can’t work in the office safely’ The over-50s leaving the UK labour force"                                           
#>  [73] "Russians Tell us what you think about Putin’s escalation of war in Ukraine"                                             
#>  [74] "Iranians Share your views on the protests following Mahsa Amini’s death"                                                
#>  [75] "Tell us How have you been affected by the situation in Ukraine?"                                                        
#>  [76] "Get in touch Share a story with the Guardian"                                                                           
#>  [77] "Podcast Can Twitter survive Elon Musk? (And can Musk survive Twitter?)"                                                 
#>  [78] "Listen to previous episodes"                                                                                            
#>  [79] "Anywhere but Washington Moral panic, culture wars and Ron DeSantis: will Florida stay red in 2022?"                     
#>  [80] "Ukraine A village brutalised by Russia, and the youth rebuilding homes and hope"                                        
#>  [81] "Rishi Sunak How he became UK PM: three days in three minutes"                                                           
#>  [82] "China Could Xi follow Putin's example and try to annex Taiwan?"                                                         
#>  [83] "US Can abortion rights swing the midterm elections?"                                                                    
#>  [84] "Heating and eating Can cost of living and climate protesters join forces?"                                              
#>  [85] "Ukraine How Russia’s strategy failed, not the tank"                                                                     
#>  [86] "'I feel like the Beyoncé of Brazilian politics' The trans woman fighting back against Bolsonaro"                        
#>  [87] "Iran What the latest footage tells us about the regime"                                                                 
#>  [88] "Galloping horses, spears and adrenaline In tent pegging 'anything can happen'"                                          
#>  [89] "‘Extraordinary treasure trove’ Saul Leiter’s unseen images"                                                             
#>  [90] "Wednesday’s best photos Panda diplomacy and circus skills"                                                              
#>  [91] "The things left behind Seould police display belongings found after crowd crush – in pictures"                          
#>  [92] "Indigenous Australians Vigils held across Australia for Cassius Turvey"                                                 
#>  [93] "Village people The rituals of rural life"                                                                               
#>  [94] "Mexico Day of the Dead celebrations"                                                                                    
#>  [95] "Grain deal U-turn offers lesson in calling Vladimir Putin’s bluff"                                                      
#>  [96] "Live Russia-Ukraine war live news: Blinken hails Turkish help as grain export deal resumes"                             
#>  [97] "Hong Kong exiles in UK unnerved by ‘weak’ response to beating of protester"                                             
#>  [98] "‘We need your help’: young girl throws note over fence at Manston"                                                      
#>  [99] "North Korea ICBM launch may have been a failure, South’s military says"                                                 
#> [100] "Zelenskiy labels Putin U-turn on Ukraine grain deal a ‘failure of Russian aggression’"                                  
#> [101] "Bahraini death row prisoner pleads with pope to aid his release"                                                        
#> [102] "No more drinking water, little food: our island is a field of bones"                                                    
#> [103] "Russia-Ukraine war at a glance: what we know on day 253 of the invasion"                                                
#> [104] "Father of three-year-old blames China’s zero-Covid policy for son’s death"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[@data-link-name='article'and not(contains(@class, 'u-faux-block-link__overlay'))]
```

This picks the headlines and the subheadlines as well.

Comment: Have you tested this? I get duplicates of the titles.

Comment: Good catch, I ve edited the Answer again.
The Blocks acted as duplicate because of the wild card !